# JavaScript, Divs not moving back to initial position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom-events

I have 3 links on the center of the page that when you click on them it makes a div appear on the right and the links move to the left of the page. I want the links to move back to the center of the page once all of the divs display is equal hidden. Also, is there any way that I can make the divs appear on the first click instead of the second click.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tk8gkrho/1/

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="link">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="box1"> box1 </a></li>
            <li><a id="box2"> box2 </a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
  
<div id="display1">
    <img src="http://globalgamejam.org/sites/default/files/styles/game_sidebar__normal/public/game/featured_image/promo_5.png?itok=9dymM8JD">
</div>

<div id="display2">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/a1/e3/6b/a1e36bcb8ce179bd8cc8db28ff4ef6fb.jpg">
</div>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
var link = document.getElementsByClassName("link")
var box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
var box2 = document.getElementById("box2");


var display1 = document.getElementById("display1");
var display2 = document.getElementById("display2");

function movingLeft(){
    for( var i = 0; i < link.length ; i++)
    {
        link[i].style.float = "left";
        link[i].style.paddingLeft = "20px";
        link[i].style.position = "fixed";
    }
};

function backToCenter(){
    if( (display1.style.display === "none") &&
        (display2.style.display === "none") )
        { 
            for( var i = 0; i < link.length; i++)
                link[i].style.float = "";
                link[i].style.position = "initial";
        }
}

box1.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(display1.style.display === "none"){
        display1.style.display = "block";
        display1.style.float = "right";
        movingLeft();
    }
    else{
        display1.style.display = "none";
        backToCenter();
    }   
});

box2.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(display2.style.display === "none"){
        display2.style.display = "block";
        display2.style.float = "right";
        movingLeft();
    }
    else{
        display2.style.display = "none";
        backToCenter();
    }   
});
```

This is my CSS:

```
.link{
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li{
    height: 13vh;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}

li a {
    height: 75%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background-color: rgba(79,87,89,0.9);
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 10vh;
    transition: background-color 0.9s;
}

li a:hover{
    background-color: black;
    border: 2px solid white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#display1{
    display: none;
    float:right;
    background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.8); 
    color: white;
    width: 60%;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

#display1 img{
    width: 80%;
    height: 30%;
}

#display2{
    display: none;
    float:right;
    background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.8); 
    color: white;
    width: 60%;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

#display2 img{
    width: 80%;
    height: 30%;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tk8gkrho/1/

I'm sorry it's kind of long, I'm still learning.

Comment: I only see two "links" (boxes) in the middle of the page.

Comment: much simpler to move/re-dimension containers than multiple individual elements. Also easier to toggle classes than do all that inline style...especially when you need to remove unwanted style. CSS  rules do all that for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can center those links using only css no need to center them in you javascript code , to do this I used `display:inline-block` and add a container to all you html and made its `text-align:center;`

and also fixed the problem of showing the divs on first click by toggle `active class` on links click

https://jsfiddle.net/tk8gkrho/2/

Your html after adding the container :

```
<div class="myContainer">
  <div class="link">
    <ul>
      <li><a id="box1"> box1 </a></li>
      <li><a id="box2"> box2 </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="display1">
    <img src="http://globalgamejam.org/sites/default/files/styles/game_sidebar__normal/public/game/featured_image/promo_5.png?itok=9dymM8JD">
  </div>

  <div id="display2">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/a1/e3/6b/a1e36bcb8ce179bd8cc8db28ff4ef6fb.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.myContainer{
  text-align:center;
}
.link{
    width: 30%;
    display:inline-block;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li{
    height: 13vh;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}

li a {
    height: 75%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background-color: rgba(79,87,89,0.9);
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 10vh;
    transition: background-color 0.9s;
}

li a:hover{
    background-color: black;
    border: 2px solid white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#display1{
    display: none;
    float:right;
    background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.8); 
    color: white;
    width: 60%;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

#display1 img{
    width: 80%;
    height: 30%;
}

#display2{
    display: none;
    float:right;
    background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.8); 
    color: white;
    width: 60%;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

#display2 img{
    width: 80%;
    height: 30%;
}

#display1.active, #display2.active{display:block;}
```

and the script :

```
var box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
var box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
var display1 = document.getElementById("display1");
var display2 = document.getElementById("display2");

box1.addEventListener("click", function(){
    display1.classList.toggle('active');
});

box2.addEventListener("click", function(){
    display2.classList.toggle('active');
});
```